# Trouble using the same name for a list in Racket after removing an element

Tags: racket

I am attempting to create a simple Hangman application in Racket. I am using a list data structure to hold the letters of the alphabet, and removing the letter the player guesses when they guess a letter from the list. However, I am getting the following error:

> (define unguessed-letters (remove "a" unguessed-letters))
>   define-values: assignment disallowed; 
>    cannot re-define a constant 
>     constant: unguessed-letters

Looks like I am unable to reuse "unguessed-letters" for the list after it has been changed? Is there a way to work around this or a different approach I should be taking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign a new value to an existing variable, you can use `set!`:

```
(set! unguessed-letters (remove "a" unguessed-letters))
```

However if you're using `set!` to mutate variables like this, you're doing so-called imperative programming. Although that's permitted in Racket, it's usually not the best way to go about it. See [Guidelines for Using Assignment](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/set_.html#%28part._using-set!%29).